# jquery pageless ruby on rails : template missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I do in pageless scrolling using jquery pageless. my file are                                                                                                  In Game Controller

```
def result
  @game = GameResult.group("game_id").where(@where).order('registered_date desc')
  @results = @game.paginate(:per_page => 3, :page => params[:page])   
  if request.xhr?
    sleep(3) # make request a little bit slower to see loader :-)
    render :partial => @results
  end
end
```

In application.html.erb

It has a div and yield file include in div tag.

In application Helper,

```
def pageless(total_pages, url=nil, container=nil)
  opts = {
      :totalPages => total_pages,
      :url        => url,
      :loaderMsg  => 'Loading more results',
     # :loaderImage => image_path("load.gif")
    }    
  container && opts[:container] ||= container    
  javascript_tag("$('#results').pageless(#{opts.to_json});")
end
```

In route

```
get '/games' =>'games#result'  
get '/games/result' => 'games#result'
rake route in terminal
games GET    /games(.:format)    games#result
```

In View under games , I have two file - result.html file and _result.html file                       result.html.erb file

```
<%= render(:partial => 'result', :collection => @results) %>
<%= will_paginate(@results) %>
<%= pageless(@results.total_pages,games_path,"#results") %>
<style>#results {overflow:auto;}</style>
```

_result.html.erb file

```
<div style="margin-bottom:3em">
<div><%= result.level %></div>
<div><%= result.game_timing %></div>
</div>
```

with this code I got the template missing error like this when i scrolling down . `" Missing partial game_results/game_result with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip]" ....` What wrong with this code.